# Get the first unique value in a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I want to get the first unique value in the first column, `Col_1` and return its corresponding row. In its simplified form, the table looks like this:

```
      Col_1   Col_2  Col_3   .......
0       A      12     R14    .......
1       B      71     R10    .......
2       A      20     R35    .......
3       F      23     R67    .......
4       D      53     R12    .......
5       B      89     R14    .......
6       F      60     R87    .......
7       A      45     R91    .......
8       B      18     R56    .......
9       C      13     R19    .......
```

Intended Outcome:

```
      Col_1   Col_2  Col_3   .......
0       A      12     R14    .......
1       B      71     R10    .......
2       F      23     R67    .......
3       D      53     R12    .......
4       C      13     R19    .......
```

I started with:

```
unique = df['Col_1'].unique().tolist()
```

to create a list of all the unique values. and now I'm stuck. Please help :D

Comment: just drop the duplicates based on the first column : `df.drop_duplicates('Col_1')`

Comment: OMG! your a lifesaver. After reading .drop_duplicates docs in pandas.
`df.drop_duplicates(subset='Col_1', keep='first', inplace=True) `
works